# Local DNS to resolve intranet address

Tags: networking, dns, intranet

My question is:

- I have a Windows 7 PC connected to Intranet, with DNS and everything is working normal. (Using wireless connection).
- I want to install DNS server on this PC, working on Ethernet connection network.

My goal is, I’ll use this DNS function to resolve a specific address on Intranet. So the client connects to Ethernet network with private IP, could reach an Intranet address on wireless network.

Please help as is it possible to work in that way, and if yes, how could I do that?

Comment: You want to set up NAT and make a router.  Although you could also set up a DNS server, but if your wired client can get out to the world they may as well use one of the DNS servers already out there, etc.  Windows calls this "internet connection sharing" and probably has a wizard to do it.  Those of us on the *nix side simply enable packet forwarding and set up routing rules.

Comment: What if I want to do DNS server but running only in wired network? I don't want the priv client asking for DNS on intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a DNS server on windows 7, and use that to provide addresses in your local domain only. You'd need to specify your ISP's DNS Addresses as forwarders otherwise machines that use your DNS Server won't be able to resolve external addresses.

There are a few pieces of software out there, you'll need to google them , as I've never used one, and can't recommend one. You could also use an old desktop as a linux server, and handle all DNS and DHCP for your network on that, and set the internet router to 1 to 1 nat.

alternatively, If you have a router installed already in your network, it will likely already have some DNS service installed, and will automatically add any hostname that requests an IP from it (if configured for DHCP).